# Query to retrieve days with no data

Tags: sql, db2

We have a staging table (DB2) that receives production numbers on a daily basis from our plant.

Because of the occasional network outage, there may be days we receive no data. I am trying to create a sql query to retrieve the days but it is not working out

```
SELECT MODDATE,
COUNT(DISTINCT EWDF) AS COUNT 
FROM PROD_FACT 
WHERE MODDATE=CURRENT_DATE - 7 DAYS 
GROUP BY MODDATE 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT EWDF)=0
```

I was expecting something like this

```
MODDATE    COUNT          
---------- -----------
09/30/2011     0

  1 record(s) selected.
```

but to no avail. I get no rows returned. What am I missing??

Comment: How would it pull back a row if there are no counts? Doesn't that mean the row (and thus the date) doesn't exist in the table?

Comment: @mwan: you're a genius and I am an uber-dunce. I realized that once I posted this message (slap forehead). We are going to create a time dimension that will allow us to left join and output the days with no data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to have a sub query and use a not in.

Perhaps something like this:

```
select prod_fact.moddate
from
prod_fact
where
prod_fact.moddate not in
(
  SELECT distinct MODDATE
  FROM PROD_FACT 
  WHERE MODDATE = CURRENT_DATE - 7 DAYS 
)
```